# C programming Sorting Function Error

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I have this function. I'm working on for class and I need a little help about why I'm getting this error.

Below is a snippet of coding:

```
int testArray[] = {...};

void display(int testArray, int nItems)
{
   int loopCounter;

   printf("[");

   for(loopCounter = 0; loopCounter < nItems; loopCounter++)
   {
      printf("%d", testArray[loopCounter]);
   }

   printf("]");
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
       if(testArray[loopCounter]);
```

However, this is exactly what the professor wanted us to do, so i'm a bit confused as to why I'm getting this error. Any ideas?

Comment: your `testArray` should be a `int*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you've used the wrong type for the array, the correct one is `int *`

```
int testArray[] = {...};

void display(int* testArray, int nItems)
{
   int loopCounter;

   printf("[");

   for(loopCounter = 0; loopCounter < nItems; loopCounter++)
   {
      printf("%d", testArray[loopCounter]);
   }

   printf("]");
}
```

Comment: I can't believe this was it. The * changed it to a pointer, right?

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you! Just have to figure out how to do something called "Deletion by searchKey".....

Comment: Don't forget to make your question solved! ;) It helps a lot!